# How can I print a ctemplate::TemplateDictionary in JSON form?

Tags: c++, json

Using the [*Google CTemplate*](http://ctemplate.googlecode.com/) library, I have built a `TemplateDictionary` of params. Such a dictionary is a map of string keys to a variety of value types.

Typically, one passes *CTemplate* a template file wherein placeholders for each key in the dictionary are found and substituted.

In one case, though, I wish to emit the entire dictionary in JSON form, and the template language syntax doesn't appear to provide reflection such that I can write placeholders to loop over an unknown number of unknown keys in any arbitrary dictionary.

- Did I miss some functionality?
- If so, how can I add it?
- Will I have to patch the *CTemplate* code? Much of what I seem to need for the job appears to be marked `private` i.e. for internal use only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up hacking the *CTemplate* source in `template_dictionary.h` and `template_dictionary.cc`, cloning class `class TemplateDictionary::DictionaryPrinter` to produce a new class `class TemplateDictionary::DictionaryJsonPrinter`, adapting its member functions to emit JSON syntax.